# How to tap OK button in permission dialog that required to access to photos on iOS using Xamarin.UITest?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.UITest to execute automation on iOS app.

The problem is that: while accessing gallery to upload a photo, there is a permission dialog and i need to tap "OK" button to dismiss it.

The following ways that i tried, but they didn't work:

- Using tree command does not show hierarchy of that dialog, so that i
  can not locate UI element to automate
- Using
  `iOSApp.InvokeUia("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().buttons()[\"OK\"].tap()");`
  This shown error:
  `UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().alert().buttons()["OK"] could
  not be tapped because the element is not visible tap@[native code]`
- Using `app.TapCoordinate`, it seems that it is able to work, but have to know the correct coordinate depends on different screens and when dialog appears.

Are there any solution to work on this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

System dialogs for permissions are outside the scope of the app and won't show up in `tree` or any other query that you can do through UITest. Instead, these are typically handled automatically by calabash. The "automatic" behavior is to accept any permission dialog that appears.

Is your dialog in a different language where "OK" might be displayed in a non-english language? If so, we may need to file an issue for that specific locale so it can be implemented.

Also, make sure you have the latest UITest version. Take a look at the changes for iOS 10 and InvokeUia [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/DeviceAgent).

Comment: This is the correct question. However, when using the Test Recorder, it does not automatically dismiss the dialog. The auto OK also means that you cannot make UI tests for cases where the user refuses the permission.

Comment: Interesting point about XTR, I will follow up on that. You might consider using a "backdoor" technique for different paths that don't rely on actually accepting permissions so you can branch behaviors that you want to test. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

Comment: Just an update to this discussion. The new version of Xamarin Test Recorder actually automatically dismisses the permission. @PhucThai should probably accept this answer as this is the most correct.

Answer (score 2):

try this:
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().elements()[0].elements()[2].elements()[1].tap()

Answer (score 0):

If you use Repl(); in your code you can try to get the marking for the OK button with the tree command.

If you are using the Visual Studio Entrerprise Edition you can make your tests a lot easier using the Xamarin Test Recorder, it works fantastically!

Another thing that should be noted is that UI Tests are usually made for screenshots and screen layout validations, the functionality of your should be tested with another kind of test with another framework or toolkit.

Comment: This doesn't work. The OK button is not in the visual tree for the application as it is launched from the OS and not the app.

Comment: Any solution/update to this? I'm facing the same problem - the app asks for Notification permission when first installed, and there seems to be no way to dismiss the permission dialog. This is using Xamarin.UITest.