# Cancelling iOS permission dialog with Xamarin UITEST and App Center

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitest

Our app uses Push Notifications, and so when it is first installed on an iOS device, the OS displays a permissions dialog.

When running tests remotely in Microsoft App Center, this dialog is preventing progress through to the main screen.

How can we automatically accept this dialog?

When examining using repl() and *tree*, the dialog isn't showing in the UI elements, so we can't access it from UITEST.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317007/how-to-tap-ok-button-in-permission-dialog-that-required-to-access-to-photos-on-i) discusses it but doesn't have a solution.

Versions:
Xamarin.UITest 2.2.5
Test device: iOS 11.1.2

**Update**
This post [Managing Privacy Alerts: Location Services, APNS, Contacts](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Managing-Privacy-Alerts%3A--Location-Services%2C-APNS%2C-Contacts)

describes how to delay the startup of Calabash, to allow it to auto-cancel the dialog (I assume).

So if we can do the same in UITest with C#, this will hopefully solve the problem. Can someone point me to the equivalent way of doing this in C#?

Comment: The permission dialogs are supposed to get accepted automatically by Xamarin.UITest. This is how it is supposed to behave. The permission dialog is a system dialog, that is why you cannot see it by using `tree` in REPL.

Comment: Hi - yes, that's what I was expecting (as you say in your comment to the other post!). However, they're _not_ automatically accepted - at least not on the iOS version I'm testing on here. Any thoughts? It seems to be impossible to get support for UITest on App Center at the moment.

Comment: This must be a bug in the framework. Alternatively make a backdoor that disables these Push Notifications for now :-/

Comment: I don't think a backdoor will work - the system dialog is there because, I think, the info.plist has Push Notifications checked.

Comment: So where do I post to get someone to look at or confirm this bug in the framework? It's a bit of a show-stopper! Any thoughts?

Comment: Interestingly, doing _app.Tap("Allow")_ does actually dismiss the system dialog. However, because the UI test system cannot see the element, I get an Exception which stops the test. I don't think I can use ExpectedException attributes on UITests.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this was happening when debugging. All I had to do was add a 2 second sleep to my test to allow Xamarin.TestUI to dismiss the popup before calling the next action in my test

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you SO MUCH. It was driving me crazy